# Kibana piped aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is it possible for perform a 'piped' aggregation within Kibana?

For example i have a ES table with auditing information in it, each document represents some action taken by a user against a system (fields: [ user, clientip, timestamp ]).

I can easily use Kibana to chart this information and show a naive plot of 'concurrent' users in say 1 hour or 5 minute bins:

- Unique Count of the `user` field for the Y Axis
- Date Histogram of the `timestamp` field for the X Axis

But as you zoom out on the chart (and encompass a larger period of data), the statistics are misleading if you wanted to interpret the Y Axis as the number of concurrent users - if the x-Axis auto scales to bins of 1 day or 1 week, you're not seeing concurrent users, your actually seeing the unique count of users (as the Y-Axis aggregation was configured).

How i think this should be shown would be a 'piped' aggregation (something i've made up not knowing a better word for it), where i'd like a unique count of users per 5 minute time window, and then a max of that count over the encompassing bins when the X-Axis auto scales to say 1/12/24 hours (so for a 1 hour bar, you get the max count of the 12x5 minute window segments)

Any thoughts / suggestions?

(Kibana 4.1.8, ES 1.7.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piped or bucket aggregations are possible since Kibana version 5.4. I have included a screenshot of a [piped Kibana visualization in Kibana 5.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Yhj.png) showing the average of a count in a date histogram.